# physics body in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

While I follow a tutorial on how to create a game using a sprite kit, I created a physics body for scene like this:

```
@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,5);
    SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"nn_03"];
    ball.position= CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.height/2];

    [self addChild:ball];
```

And when I checked it, it work just with upper and lower bounded of the scene and doesn't work with left and right side of the scene ? Where is the problem ?

And my second question when i downgrade my Xcode 6 to Xcode 5 , can i target iOS 8 IN XCODE 5 OR NOT ?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?  Also, please don't ask multiple questions in the same question.  Create two different questions if you need help with more than one issue.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, i did the code above to get bouned for my scene but it's work with upper and lower bound of scene and doesn't work with right and left sides , in the left and right sides the ball goes away . Although i double checked and it was correct programmatically.